# Scroll div on click

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple list which is displayed horizontally and set the scrollbar hidden.

I add two buttons to scroll the list to left and right, and adjust the list showing another 3 items.

My problem is the hidden data is not showing, I tried to use margin but only the container element is moving when clicking the left button.

```js
$('ul li').each(function(i){
    var index = i+1;
    $(this).find('span').html(index);
});


var list = $('ul');
var listItems = list.children('li');
list.append(listItems.get().reverse());

$('.control .left').click(function(){
    $('.list').css('scrollLeft', 1500);
});
```

```css
ul li{
  width: 45px;
  height: 101px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.list{
  width: 330px;
height: 101px;
overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #DDD;
  float: left;
}
ul{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.control{
  float: left;
}
.control div{
  background-color: #DDD;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.control span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="control">
  <div class="left"><span><</span></div>
  <div class="right"><span>></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `scroll` without `scrollbar`. You need to work with other positions ...

Comment: it works [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_scrollleft_set) sir

Comment: Yes, because there is a `scrollbar`, so it can use `scrollLeft`.

Comment: try to change the overflow to hidden

Answer (score 0):

You example has many issues:

- you need to escape `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` in html
- in the example you posted, it uses `.scrollLeft(100)`, but you use `.css('scrollLeft', 150)`, what will not work
- Your `li` elements are not in a single line, the are wraped because of your styling, so there is no horizontal scroll
- Change the `hidden` overflow to `auto` to become a scrollbar available

```js
$('ul li').each(function(i){
    var index = i+1;
    $(this).find('span').html(index);
});


var list = $('ul');
var listItems = list.children('li');
list.append(listItems.get().reverse());

$('.control .right').click(function(){
    $('.list').scrollLeft(150);
});
$('.control .left').click(function(){
    $('.list').scrollLeft(0);
});
```

```css
ul li{
  width: 45px;
  height: 101px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.list{
  width: 330px;
height: 101px;
overflow: auto;
  background-color: #DDD;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.control{
  float: left;
}
.control div{
  background-color: #DDD;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.control span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    item <span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="control">
  <div class="left"><span>&lt;</span></div>
  <div class="right"><span>&gt;</span></div>
</div>
```